# How to access $menu variable in custom .PHP file that loads wp-load.php?

Tags: admin-menu, wp-load.php

I have a file `custom.php` inside the WP root folder. My goal is to access the `GLOBAL $menu` variable that stores the admin menu items. In order to do that, I try loading the WordPress environment.

```
<?php require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php'; ?>
```

After loading, I checked and made sure that the WordPress environment has been loaded.

```
if (defined('ABSPATH')) echo "WP Environment loaded."
```

Even when the wp-load.php is loaded, I am unable to access the global variable $menu which I can under a plugin file.

Is there any other file that needs to be loaded? Does the code after wp-load.php get executed after all the plugins were loaded?

Here is the whole code inside the file.

```
ROOT FOLDER
|__ customer (folder)
|   |_______test.php
|__ wp-admin
|__ wp-content
|__ ...
```

Here is what inside test.php

```
<?php

    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php';
    global $menu;

    if (defined('ABSPATH')) {

        echo "WP Environment loaded.<br>";
        echo "Admin menu returns " .json_encode( $menu );
    }

?>
```

And this is the output result:

```
WP Environment loaded.<br>Admin menu returns null
```

Comment: Share code where you are trying to access `$menu`.

Comment: @QaisarFeroz: Edited. Please take a look.

Comment: How are you setting `$menu` as global variable?

Comment: If you have properly set `$menu` as global variable then, instead of loading `wp-load.php`, try loading `wp-blog-header.php`. I hope this will work.

Comment: I did try that; and it didn't work. Please let me know if you can think of something else.